# Sequelize webservice : loading in Postman

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize with typescript and NodeJS, and I tested my webservice with postman, the request works because it's executed in database, but the request loading in postman, and I have "Could not get any response"

This is my code : (I cut my code to show you the most necessary)

```
   const lstDocs = []
            for (let MyDoc of resultReq) {

                if (MyDoc.matriculeDoc != "") {
                    lstDocs.push(sequelize.models['FolderDocContent'].findOrCreate({
                        where: {
                            FolderDocId: requestedFolderId,
                            critElem: 'DOC',
                            critValue: MyDoc.matriculeDoc
                        }
                    }))
                }
            }

            q.all(lstDocs).then(() => {
                return response.status(201)
            })
```

What's the problem with my webservice ?
Thank you

Comment: i don't see why you would get a 'findOCreate is undefined' with an asynchronous problem... Do you have a line number for the error 'findOCreate is undefined' ?

Comment: not an async issue. probably `sequelize.models['FolderDocCrit']` is undefined

Comment: @AkashDathan you're right. The model was undefined. Thank you, The request works but, postman is loading , and I have "could not get any response in postman .." I edit my answer